# Should I submit the redirects in XML sitemaps in the old website search console?

Tags: seo, redirects, xml-sitemap

I have redirected `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`. Should I exclude all the redirected pages of the first website in its own search console?

For instance should I include `https://www.example.com` in its own sitemap as the redirected page?

Answer (score 2):

Your sitemap should only contain the URLs you want to have indexed.  It should not contain:

- redirecting URLs
- duplicate URLs
- error URLs

You should delete the sitemap containing your old URLs and submit a sitemap that only contains the new URLs.

The reason is that Google uses sitemaps to choose the best URLs to index.   You don't want Google trying to index redirecting URLs.  You want Google to index the URLs at their final destination.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).